# Error in Juju configurations

Tags: 14.04, juju

I have configured Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 1 vm for MAAS-cluster, 2 VM for Nodes to connect the MAAS-cluster.

I am not able to complete juju configuration in nodes, find the below error.

```
Error details:
cannot parse "/root/.juju/environments.yaml": YAML error: line 326: could not find expected ':'
```

What should i do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your environments.yaml file can't be read because it doesn't comply with the YAML syntax. It's easy enough to mangle it if you have been editing it.

you could try http://yamllint.com/ to see where it has gone wrong, or just generate a new one. The maas section should look something like:

```
   maas:
      type: maas
      # Change this to where your MAAS server lives.  It must specify the base path.
      maas-server: 'http://192.168.1.1/MAAS/'
      maas-oauth: '<add your OAuth credentials from MAAS here>'
      # default-series: precise
      authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/authorized_keys # or any file you want.
      # Or:
      # authorized-keys: ssh-rsa keymaterialhere
```